# How can i move a shape forward in a certain angle in java?

Tags: java, graphics, rotation

I'm trying to create a game in which i can turn the rectangle around and move it forward in a certain direction or backward, when i press right it rotates clockwise and if i press left it goes counter-clockwise but i'm having this problem that if i move up or down it only rotates the same when i press right and left but i expected them to move up or down, i have looked unto other programs and tried to copy their methods but i'm still missing something out, somebody please help, thanks in advance

Here is my exact Code below:

```
 public class Rotate extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener{
 Timer t = new Timer(20,this); 
 boolean right=false;
 boolean left=false;
 boolean up=false;
 boolean down=false;
 Rectangle tank;
 int tankx=30;
 int tanky=50;
 double a;
 int angle;

 Rotate()
 {

  JFrame f = new JFrame();
  f.add(this);
  f.addKeyListener(this);
  f.setSize(1000,1000);
  f.setVisible(true);
  f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


      tank = new Rectangle(400,400,30,50);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
new Rotate();
}
int i;
 public void paint(Graphics g) {

   super.paint(g);
   Graphics2D g2d =(Graphics2D)g;


   g2d.rotate(a,tank.getWidth()+tankx/2,tank.getHeight()+tanky/2);
   g.setColor(Color.red);
   g.fillRect(tankx,tanky,tank.width,tank.height);

   if(angle>360)
   {
       angle=0;

   }
   else if(angle<0)
   {
       angle=360;

   }
    a= Math.toRadians(angle);   

    System.out.println("x");
         t.start();
}





@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

 if(right==true)
 {

       angle+=4;

 }
 else if(left==true)
 {


      angle-=4; 

 }   
 else if(down==true)
 {
  angle-=4;
  tank.x-=Math.cos(a);
  tank.y-=Math.sin(a);   

 }
 else if(up==true)
 {
  angle+=4;
  tank.x+=Math.cos(a);
  tank.y+=Math.sin(a);   

 }
    repaint();
     }



@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
  {
      right=true;
  }
  else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
  {
      left=true;
  }
  else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
  {
     up=true;
  }
  else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
  {
      down=true;
  }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  right=false;
  left=false;
  up=false;
  down=false;
}
```

}

Comment: `tank.x += Math.cos(a);`  since `a` is only updated during the next paint cycle, the best you have is the "previous" state

Comment: im sorry i dont get it could you ellaborate a bit please

Comment: You're relying on `a`'s value, but `a` is only update when the component is painted, therefore, when you move up or down, you're not using the current rotation, but the previous

Comment: thanks for that insight now i get why it behaves that way, could you recommend something out in how could i not use the previous in up and down? or edit the code a bit , im sorry if it bothers you

Answer (score 0):

`g.fillRect(tankx, tanky, tank.width, tank.height);`   When does `tankx` or `tanky` actually change?

Because you're modifying the underling `Graphics` context on each paint cycle, you are running the risk of compounding the rotation.  Better to use `Graphics#create` to create a snapshot of its current state and then modify that.  Just remember to call `Graphics#dispose` on the copy

Remember, when you rotating the `Graphics` context, you are rotating the origin point (0x0) as well, so movement will no longer by "up" or "down", but will be relative to the angle the of rotation.

So, this is a modification of your code.  I've updated the `paint` method (you really should be using `paintComponent`) so that the origin is translated to the position of the tank (this makes `0x0` the position of the tank), it then becomes much easier to rotate.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Rotate extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    Timer t = new Timer(20, this);
    boolean right = false;
    boolean left = false;
    boolean up = false;
    boolean down = false;
    Rectangle tank;
    int angle;

    Rotate() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.add(this);
        f.addKeyListener(this);
        f.setSize(1000, 1000);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        tank = new Rectangle(400, 400, 30, 50);
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Rotate();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        double radian = Math.toRadians(angle);
        g2d.translate(tank.x, tank.y);
        g2d.rotate(radian, tank.getWidth() / 2, tank.getHeight() / 2);
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, tank.width, tank.height);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (right == true) {

            angle += 4;
            System.out.println("Right");

        } else if (left == true) {

            angle -= 4;
            System.out.println("Left");

        } else if (down == true) {
            angle -= 4;
            double radian = Math.toRadians(angle);
            tank.x -= Math.cos(radian);
            tank.y -= Math.sin(radian);
            System.out.println("Down: " + tank.x + "x" + tank.y);

        } else if (up == true) {
            angle += 4;
            double radian = Math.toRadians(angle);
            tank.x += Math.cos(radian);
            tank.y += Math.sin(radian);
            System.out.println("Up: " + tank.x + "x" + tank.y);

        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = true;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = true;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up = true;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        right = false;
        left = false;
        up = false;
        down = false;
    }
}
```

I also think you have you `cos`/`sin` around the wrong way and up should subtract and down should add - but this is solely based on observations.

You might want to have a look at:

- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/36046/how-do-i-make-an-entity-move-in-a-direction
- [Calculate the movement of a point with an angle in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127413/calculate-the-movement-of-a-point-with-an-angle-in-java)
- [Basic rotation and Moving toward angle direction (car movement)](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/basic-rotation-and-moving-toward-angle-direction-car-movement/29407/view.html)

for more ideas